# Where to change the buildToolsVersion in IONIC project

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build.gradle

Hey friends I am facing an issue in my IONIC project

found the solution is to upgrade the buildToolsVersion in the build.gradle file but can anyone help me where exactly need to change the value

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt                                                                                       * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.                                                  (node:7332) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                            Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                            values-v26\values-v26.xml:15:21-54: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.                                                                                                                 values-v26\values-v26.xml:15: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.                             > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt                                                                                       * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update your Android SDk, and accepts licences.

And run these commands before building the app :

### **UNIX**

```
  export ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_cdvCompileSdkVersion=android-26
  export ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_cdvBuildToolsVersion=26.0.1
```

### **WINDOWS**

```
  set ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_cdvCompileSdkVersion=android-26
  set ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_cdvBuildToolsVersion=26.0.1
```